# How to replace Youtube urls in text with embeded code (in PHP)?

Tags: php, youtube, embed

This is what I've got so far:

```
<?php

 $content = "word1 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqfKe-67foQ&feature=related word2 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vq7gDEn99Y&feature=related word3 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nW5HxgMYRto\nhttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Uc2lpH0iZ0&feature=fvhl";
 $pattern = '/http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?(.*)v=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)(\S*)/i';
 $replace = '<object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/$2&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/$2&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed></object>';

 $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $content);
 echo $content;

?>
```

I honestly have no idea why it doesn't work. Some help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try just filter the video id...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to make `*` non-greedy:

```
http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?(.*?)v=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)(\S*)
```

See ["Watch out for greediness"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple function for URL replacement

```
function youtube($string)
{
  return preg_replace(
    '#(http://(www.)?youtube.com)?/(v/|watch\?v\=)([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)&?.*?#i',
    '<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    $string
  );
}

echo youtube('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWsjWCt1PsQ');
echo youtube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=VWsjWCt1PsQ');
echo youtube('http://youtube.com/v/VWsjWCt1PsQ');
echo youtube('http://www.youtube.com/v/VWsjWCt1PsQ');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a string with a configured embed code. Link attribute could be `#LINK#`, `width="#WIDTH#"`. Than replace all parameters with your own value. It could be much more comfortable to use. Or you can simply use a [youtube embed code generator](http://online-marketing-technologies.com/tools/youtube-embed-code-generator.html) for that.